# Java Convert Jar URL to File

Tags: java, file, url, jar, uri

I am trying to achieve the following: From a given `Class` object, I want to be able to retrieve the folder or file in which it is located. This should also work for System classes like `java.lang.String` (which would return the location of `rt.jar`). For 'source' classes, the method should return the root folder:

```
- bin
  - com
    - test
      - Test.class
```

would return the location of the `bin` folder for `file(com.test.Test.class)`. This is my implementation so far:

```
public static File getFileLocation(Class<?> klass)
{
    String classLocation = '/' + klass.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";
    URL url = klass.getResource(classLocation);
    String path = url.getPath();
    int index = path.lastIndexOf(classLocation);
    if (index < 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Jar Handling
    if (path.charAt(index - 1) == '!')
    {
        index--;
    }
    else
    {
        index++;
    }

    int index1 = path.lastIndexOf(':', index);
    String newPath = path.substring(index1 + 1, index);

    System.out.println(url.toExternalForm());
    URI uri = URI.create(newPath).normalize();

    return new File(uri);
}
```

However, this code fails because the `File(URI)` constructor throws an `IllegalArgumentException` - "URI is not absolute". I already tried to use the `newPath` to construct the file, but this failed for directory structures with spaces, like this one:

```
- Eclipse Workspace
  - MyProgram
    - bin
      - Test.class
```

This is due to the fact that the URL representation uses `%20` to denote a whitespace, which is not recognized by the file constructor.

Is there an efficient and reliable way to get the (classpath) location of a Java class, which works for both directory structures and Jar files?

Note that I don't need the exact file of the exact class - only the container! I use this code to locate `rt.jar` and the language library for using them in a compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight modification in your code should work here. You can try below code:

```
public static File getFileLocation(Class<?> klass)
{
    String classLocation = '/' + klass.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";
    URL url = klass.getResource(classLocation);
    String path = url.getPath();
    int index = path.lastIndexOf(classLocation);
    if (index < 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    String fileCol = "file:";
    //add "file:" for local files
    if (path.indexOf(fileCol) == -1)
    {
        path = fileCol + path;
        index+=fileCol.length();
    }

    // Jar Handling
    if (path.charAt(index - 1) == '!')
    {
        index--;
    }
    else
    {
        index++;
    }

    String newPath = path.substring(0, index);

    System.out.println(url.toExternalForm());
    URI uri = URI.create(newPath).normalize();

    return new File(uri);
}
```

Hope this will help.